# Move cursor left and right without arrow keys Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, key-bindings

How can I move left and right in Visual Studio *without* pressing arrow keys? Ideally I would like to press right-alt and a character.

Comment: Could you please explain why? Doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign custom shortcuts to **Edit.CharLeft** and **Edit.CharRight** commands in VS keyboard options.

Answer (score 0):

Go to visual studio's **-> keyboard shortcut**, then search for *cursorleft*, for moving cursor to left and *cursorright*, for moving cursor to the right. Assign key according to your choice. By default it would be assigned to *left arrow* and *right arrow* keys.